# SQLite Error in statement insert with question mark

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

Hello I am writing a query to insert values in DB SQLite.

Firstly, I read from my records and searched for two values, for example, then I created a new table and inserted new values in.

My code snippet follows:

```
try
  {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:tests.db");
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate("delete msearch");
    ResultSet res=st.executeQuery("select * from newmobile_details");
    Boolean rec=res.next();
    if(!rec)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"لايوجد سجلات");
    }
    else
    {
      do
      {
        String mid=res.getString(1);
        String model=res.getString(2);
        String name=res.getString(3);
        int price=res.getInt(4);
        String pcolor=res.getString(5);
        String imei=res.getString(6);
        java.sql.Date date=res.getDate(7);
        String access=res.getString(8);

        if(mname.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
        {
          PreparedStatement prp=con.prepareStatement("insert into msearch values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
          prp.setString(1,mid);
          prp.setString(2,model);
          prp.setString(3,name);
          prp.setInt(4,price);
          prp.setString(5,pcolor);
          prp.setString(6,imei);
          prp.setDate(7,date);
          prp.setString(8,access);

          prp.executeUpdate();

          System.out.println("iam inside2");
          rows++;

          b=1;
          jTextField2.setText("");
        }


     }while(res.next());

     if(b==0)
     {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"لم يتم العثور على الموبايل ");
       jTextField2.setText("");
     }
   }
   con.commit();
   con.close();
 }

 catch(Exception e)
 {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The error is1:" +e);
 }
```

I get only exception as below:

> The error is1 :sql error or missing database in msearch syntax error

Comment: This is not the complete error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Larry makes a good point and looking at your code more carefully I believe the problem is with the statement

```
st.executeUpdate("delete msearch");
```

It seems to be saying you should be qualifying `msearch` with a database name.

---

This is the syntax for an insert statement

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (c1, c2, c3,...cN)  
VALUES (v1, v2, v3,...vN);
```

You give a list of column names and a list of values.

You don't have the list of column names.

This can't work.

Comment: This is not correct.  It's certainly *preferable* to explicitly name the columns, but a values-only `INSERT` is allowed syntax.  The number of values specified must exactly match the number of columns in the table.  Without knowing the table structure it's not possible to know if this is the source of the error.